# Why do mobile games have delays for certain actions?

Tags: turn-based, monetization

Many phone games restrict the number of actions you can take in a given amount of time. I don't get what is the purpose of this limitation. Is it only to force the player to buy additional turns? Some games don't even allow this for some turn "kinds" (like action A can be played again by spending real money while action B cannot be played again by spending money).

Another possible reason would be to limit the bandwidth usage to their server and make it more predictable over time, but I can't see phone games using so much data.

Comment: This is simply a developer's choice - if its not for monetization, the only other reason i can think of is to prolong the length of the game to keep interest. Without these times to wait the game might reveal to be short and that can hinder popularity or longevity of the game. Other than that no one can speak on the developer's behalf on why they choose to do it.

Comment: as Dave said, it's just developers choice. and "many games" really depends on your perspective..

Comment: What are "many phone games"? Unclear. These games would have different reasons for having limited turns: Too Broad.

Answer (score 3):

If you can buy more turns then it's for monetization.

The non-buyable turns are to keep you playing over time. You have no choice but to wait until they regenerate which means you will come back the next day to spend them and then see the advertisement to buy more turns of the other kind.

If it is a multiplayer game then the goal is usually to limit the grinding options and keep casual and hardcore gamers at roughly the same level.

Answer (score 3):

1. It's an easy way to make money from addicted players. You're so close to the goal, but you die. You can pay $5 to replenish your lives now or wait 2 hours. You want to play one more turn but you can't, unless you wait or pay. Repeat indefinitely because you're addicted and...
2. ... the game enforces delays so that you have something to return to later. Instead of going through the game quickly, you split your gameplay over a large period of time, with short sessions of play. This fits the mobile market well because people have their devices with them all the time, and boring moments can be filled with their favorite game instead. Usually, around that time, the delays have expired and the game has something new to show the players.

Fragmented gameplay also helps alleviate the impact of paying real money. For example, the user may not be likely to spend $10 in a single session, but he may be likely to spend $10 in a few more sessions with N days in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting turns is a general way of equalizing a game, making sure it balances.

For example, in online MMORPGs, players with fast computers or a fast internet connection would otherwise be unbeatable, while players with a slow connection would constantly fail in a game. (This already happens, but it is a much less severe imbalance *because* of turn limiting).

Also, it can be used in some cases to prevent people from benefiting disproportionately from automated scripts that help them win a game. Even if their script pumps commands into the game at a high speed, their character can't move faster than any other player, or NPCs they are competing with.

By limiting the number of actions to be done over time, you limit everything else, and make it possible to have e.g. an enemy that is intentionally impossible to win against. (E.g. at the edge of a map). Or you can have an enemy at the gate to a dangerous area that threatens (but does not damage) players of a lower level, and that way prevents beginners from accidentally walking into e.g. a PvP area before they're powerful enough.

This problem was for example the reason for the "Turbo" button on old PCs. Turning off the Turbo would force the CPU to run at half-speed, like the previous models. If you didn't do that, games that didn't limit the number of turns would run too fast, and became unplayable.

It's a tried-and-true technique, you also have the same concept in most board and card games, where each player takes a turn before the next one is permitted to do theirs.

Comment: Bandwidth != Latency. Also, Your turbo description is bad programming. It's using clock cycles as a timer instead of writing a HPT to manage game time.